# Count Distinct Composite Columns

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to count distinct composite columns using sql. Below is my query

```
SELECT distinct_val.LeaseTenantSSN, count(distinct_val.LeaseTenantSSN) = 3
FROM (select distinct houseid, LeaseTenantSSN from tenants) AS distinct_val 
group by distinct_val.LeaseTenantSSN;
```

Result

[image: Result]

What I want to get is

```
SELECT distinct_val.LeaseTenantSSN
FROM (select distinct houseid, LeaseTenantSSN from tenants) AS distinct_val 
where count(distinct_val.LeaseTenantSSN) = 3
group by distinct_val.LeaseTenantSSN;
```

But it gives error on where statement. I am using Postgresql

Comment: My answer below might make the error go away, but I don't understand your query.  Please post sample data clearly showing what the problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `HAVING`:

```
SELECT distinct_val.LeaseTenantSSN
FROM (select distinct houseid, LeaseTenantSSN from tenants) AS distinct_val 
group by distinct_val.LeaseTenantSSN
having count(distinct_val.LeaseTenantSSN) = 3
```

This may fix your error, but I suspect that you really want something like the following:

```
SELECT LeaseTenantSSN
FROM tenants
GROUP BY LeaseTenantSSN
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT houseid) = 3
```

This would return every tenant SSN which had exactly three distinct houses associated with him.

Comment: `having` does the job.